# We might need to be more accurate about the limits of creditation and plagiarism

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57219/what-is-this-hole-in-some-gas-related-threads), I was requested to give proper creditation to pictures I googled to give examples of what I was talking about.

In my understanding of the situation, this makes sense when the picture is something recognisable, but it is just impossible, when we are talking about a picture found on multiple (selling) sites not crediting anything, with various brands and no brand names on the product itself - which is often the case with chinese anonymous products.

In this precise situation and probably many intermediary situations, it just becomes impossible to give a proper creditation to a picture and the maker of the product itself does not seem to have the faintest interest to it. So I believe it would be a good idea to think about specify realistic limits in https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/referencing